# Content of <div> not updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got a div element which I am using as a popup which does not update itself. I'll use the picture below to explain:

[image: Popup problem]

When I click on each row in the grid, the right hand side updates to show the details, part of which is a potentially lengthy Note field. The button View Note triggers a popup with the full text inside. Here, I have previously selected Donor 2000000, which displayed the correct note. However, when I select another Donor(2000002 as highlighted)  the information in the popup retains the info for the first selected Donor. So, essentially it sets it once and then does not update.

The (partial) code for the main View is:

```
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
        <h4>
            Donor Details
        </h4>
        <div id="donor-details">
            <p class="muted">
                Select donor to display detailed infomation
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">
        @Html.Action("DonorSummaryGrid") @* configure grid in a partial view *@
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        pageGrids.donorSummaryGrid.onRowSelect(function (e) {
            $.post("/Donor/GetDonorDetails?donorId=" + e.row.DonorId, function (data) {
                if (data.Status <= 0) {
                    alert(data.Message);
                    return;
                }
                $("#donor-details").html(data.Content);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code for the partial view - which contains the details - is:

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.CurrentNoteText)) {

    <div id="note-dialog" title="Note for Donor @Model.DonorId">
        <p>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.CurrentNoteText)</p>
    </div>
    <br />
}
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/NoteDialogue.js")
```

When I debug, the value of Model.CurrentNoteText and @Model.DonorId do reflect the correct data.

NoteDialogue.js is:

```
$(function() {
    $("#note-dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 500
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 200
        }
    });

    $("#opener").click(function() {
        $("#note-dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

I hope this is clear :)

Oh, there are no errors shown in the browser, and everthing functions as expected, except for updating the info in the popup.

I have tried

```
<script>
    $("#note-dialog").html("@Model.CurrentNoteText");
</script>
```

with no success.

Comment: In `$("#note-dialog").html("@Model.CurrentNoteText");`, `@Model.CurrentNoteText` is razor code asn is parsed on the server before its sent to the view and will never be updated. You have also indicated your partial has `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/NoteDialogue.js")` - a script should never be in a partial (move it to the main view)

Answer (score 0):

Got there in the end :)

Looking at the generated source, I noticed that the code for

```
    <div id="note-dialog" title="Note for Donor @Model.DonorId">
        <p>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.CurrentNoteText)</p>
    </div>
    <br />
```

was being generated right at the bottom, outside all the other divs containing the grid and details. Looked something like this:

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" role="dialog" aria-describedby="note-dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1"....>
```

As I clicked each row with a note in, an extra div was being generated, with the aria-labelledby attribute incrementing, e.g. "ui-id-2", "ui-id-3"...

The first generated div was being selected for the dialogue opening.

The solution was to remove the div on the row click event. Code now is:

```
$(function() {
    pageGrids.donorSummaryGrid.onRowSelect(function (e) {

        $("#note-dialog").remove(); 

        $.post("/Donor/GetDonorDetails?donorId=" + e.row.DonorId, function(data) {
            if (data.Status <= 0) {
                alert(data.Message);
                return;
            }
            $("#donor-details").html(data.Content);
        });
    });
});
```